# Morphological dilation on Greyscale image using a neighborhood of size n x n in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, morphological-analysis, mathematical-morphology

***The Dilation process is performed by laying the structuring element B on the image A and sliding it across the image in a manner similar to convolution.***

I understand the main concept behind the mathematical morphology dilation of the grayscale images, but i still have one question :

Can the values of the structure element be not chosen by the user ? In other words, can we perform a dilation process on the image by just choosing the size and shape of the structure element without specifying its elements?

For more precision, i will explain well my question by an example : Assume a greyscale image `I` of size `160 x 160` to be processed (dilated in this case) by a neighborhood of size 8 x 8. I didn't specify the elements of this neighborhood, so their elements are from the image itself. For example i wrote the matlab code below:

```
Max_image = max_filter(I, [0 0 7 7]);
```

Where the function **max_filter** is:

```
[n m] = size(I); % n=160 and m=160
B = I; 
for i = 1:m-7,
    B(:,i) = max(I(:,i:i+7),[],2);
  end

 for i=m-7+1:m
    B(:,i) = max(I(:,i:min(end,i+7),[],2);
  end

 for i = 1:n-7,
    I(i,:) = max(B(max(1,i):min(end,i+7),:),[],1);
  end

  for i = n-7+1:n,
    I(i,:) = max(B(i:min(end,i+7),:),[],1);
  end
```

Does that is still considered as a morphological dilation operation ? Recall that i used a structure element of size 8 x 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is equivalent to a full image dilation with the structure element of `ones(8)` (btw, you didn't use the input argument [0 0 7 7], and you don't need that indeed):

```
I = [92    99     1     8    15    67    74    51    58    40
     98    80     7    14    16    73    55    57    64    41
      4    81    88    20    22    54    56    63    70    47
     85    87    19    21     3    60    62    69    71    28
     86    93    25     2     9    61    68    75    52    34
     17    24    76    83    90    42    49    26    33    65
     23     5    82    89    91    48    30    32    39    66
     79     6    13    95    97    29    31    38    45    72
     10    12    94    96    78    35    37    44    46    53
     11    18   100    77    84    36    43    50    27    59];
```

`Max_image = max_filter(I, [0 0 7 7])` will give you:

```
    99    99    97    97    97    75    75    75    72    72
    98    97    97    97    97    75    75    75    72    72
   100   100   100    97    97    75    75    75    72    72
   100   100   100    97    97    75    75    75    72    72
   100   100   100    97    97    75    75    75    72    72
   100   100   100    97    97    72    72    72    72    72
   100   100   100    97    97    72    72    72    72    72
   100   100   100    97    97    72    72    72    72    72
   100   100   100    96    84    59    59    59    59    59
   100   100   100    84    84    59    59    59    59    59
```

When you are using:

```
J1=imdilate(I,ones(8),'full');
J1(8:end,8:end)
```

It will give you exactly the same answer.

That's why I told you yesterday that it is often to use a binary image mask as the structure element. You don't need to choose the value inside the mask, but you need to choose the size (8*8) and shape. What is a shape? In a binary image, the elements that are filled with 1 determines the shape. Here in your code you selected the largest value within the 8*8 region, that is equivalent to the image dilation with a whole bright 8*8 square shaped mask.

Comment: So in my code, all elements within the mask define the shape true ? so the shape is a square of size 8x8 ? because all the elements are 1. i understand true ?  And in my case, this is a flat or non flat mask ? and what is the origin? i didn't understand well the concept behind flat-non flat

Comment: @Christina, I don't quite know about the definition of flat/nonflat, or and origin for a mask. But in geometry, the flats in two-dimensional space are points and lines, so I guess the mask like[0 0 0;1 1 1;0 0 0] is called flat, but ones(3) is non-flat.

Comment: jajaja ok don't worry :), anyway thank you very much and i really appreciate very much your help, you are the best.

Comment: Flat structuring elements like ones(3) and [000;111;000] both are binary valued structuring function. This depends like @lennon310 said purely on the support and not on the numerical value of the function. The numerical dilation is given by: (f+b)(x) = sup[f(y)+b(x-y)] where b is the structuring function. When inside the structuring element b(x-y)=0 when outside its Inf [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology)). Instead of 0 one can a have numerical value. This is possible in [Matlab](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/23/nonflat-grayscale-dilation-and-erosion/)